# Remove empty and null value recursively from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array like this

```
$a = array(
  'b' => array(
    'two' => false,
    'three' => '',
    'four' => null,
    'five' => array(
       'fp' => null,
       'kp' => null
    ),
    'six' => array()
  ),
  'c' => '  ',
  'd' => null
);
```

I want to remove only `null` and `empty` keys from this n-level array. And finally I should get this:

```
$a = array(
  'b' => array(
    'two' => false
  ),
  'c' => '  '
);
```

I have this function

```
public function ArrayCleaner($input) { 
  foreach ($input as &$value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $value = ArrayCleaner($value); 
    }
  }
  return array_filter($input); 
}
```

But, as [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) states, it will also remove `false` value key (that I want to preserve). So what change I should make in my function to achieve the expected result?

Comment: what about 'one' ? it should be removed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, just change your code like below by providing the callback function for filtering:

```
function ArrayCleaner($input) { 
  foreach ($input as &$value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $value = ArrayCleaner($value); 
    }
  }

  return array_filter($input, function($item){
    return $item !== null && $item !== '';
  }); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry to say, that there was an error in my example. You may see, I added some values inside `five` and added other key `six` that has empty array. So in this case, `six` should be completely removed as it does not contain any non-empty and non-null value child. Similarly `five` should be removed. And the result should be as shown in my question.

Comment: I added this `return $item !== null && $item !== '' && count($item) > 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
function ArrayCleaner($input) { 
  foreach ($input as $key=>&$value) { 
     if(is_int($key)){  
        unset($input[$key]);
        continue;
     }
    if (is_array($value)) { 
       $value = ArrayCleaner($value); 
    }
  }

  return array_filter($input, function($item){
    return $item !== null && $item !== '';
  }); 
}
```

But Question: what does empty key mean?  'one' indicates its index is number 0. So if we filter it by using  something like `is_int($key)` , how to deal with  `'2'=>'this data?'` ? it will convert to int(2) in php Array.